# mongoose subdocument virtual in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Lets say i have a comment schema. A comment can have several replies. How can i create a virtual attribute to transform each reply's `created_at` date like this? `moment(this.replies.[currentReplyIndex].created_at).format('lll')`

```
const Comment = new mongoose.Schema({ // sort: new to old by created_at
  body: String,
  replies: [{
    body: String,
    created_at: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    }
  }]
});
```

I have no idea how to do this with an array of objects subdocument structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to define your subdocument seperately:

```
var Reply = new mongoose.Schema({
   body: String,
   created_at: {
     type: Date,
     default: Date.now
   }
});

// Virtual must be defined before the subschema is assigned to parent schema
Reply.virtual("created_at").get(function() {
  // Parent is accessible
  // var parent = this.parent();
  return moment(this.created_at).format('lll');
});


var Comment = new mongoose.Schema({
   body: String,
   replies: {
      type: [Reply]
   }
});
```

Comment: Hiya, so you know, you've made a little error in your example above. It says `Variation` where it should - in your example - say `Reply`.  cheers.